# How to manually add a label to a specific part of my bar plot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following data and code which produces a barplot.

```
#generate example data
rG_activity <- c("0.230", "0.335", NA, "0.368", "0.368", "0.327", "0.091", "-0.230")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.075, 0.335)", "(0.239, 0.631)", NA, "(0.234, 0.602)", "(0.284, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.340)", "(-0.311, 0.252)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.304", "-0.302", "-0.309", "-0.362", "-0.345", "-0.291", "-0.062", "-0.291")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.242, -0.266)", "(-0.268, -0.236)","(-0.256, -0.263)", "(-0.679, -0.244)", "(-0.260, -0.231)", "(-0.396, -0.086)", "(-0.272, 0.247)", "(-0.207, -0.074)")
rE_activity <- c("0.005","-0.024", NA, "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.054", "-0.013", "0.058")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.255, 0.266)", "(0.243, -0.291)", NA,"(-0.021, 0.333)", "(-0.298, 0.048)", "(-0.248, 0.240)", "(-0.266, 0.240)", "(-0.225, 0.241)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("0.211", "-0.006", "-0.098", "0.093", "-0.002", "0.203", "0.047", "0.205")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.046, 0.269)", "(0.257, -0.269)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.065, 0.251)", "(-0.274, 0.270)", "(-0.065, 0.272)", "(-0.212, 0.206)", "(-0.071, 0.280)")
rG_emotionality <- c("0.230", "0.335", "-0.309", "0.368", "0.368", "0.327", "0.091", "-0.230")
rG_emotionality_error_intervals <- c("(-0.075, 0.335)", "(0.239, 0.631)", "(-0.256, -0.263)", "(0.234, 0.602)", "(0.284, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.340)", "(-0.311, 0.252)")
rE_emotionality <- c("0.005","-0.024", "-0.098", "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.054", "-0.013", "0.058")
rE_emotionality_error_intervals <- c("(-0.255, 0.266)", "(0.243, -0.291)", "(-0.261, 0.064)","(-0.021, 0.333)", "(-0.298, 0.048)", "(-0.248, 0.240)", "(-0.266, 0.240)", "(-0.225, 0.241)")
age <- c("slope", "intercept", "36", "30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals, rG_emotionality, rG_emotionality_error_intervals, rE_emotionality, rE_emotionality_error_intervals)

#produce figure
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df_tidy <- melt(df , measure.vars = list(values=c("rG_activity","rG_task_persistence","rE_activity","rE_task_persistence", "rG_emotionality", "rE_emotionality"),
                              intervals=c("rG_activity_error_intervals","rG_task_persistence_error_intervals","rE_activity_error_intervals","rE_task_persistence_error_intervals", "rG_emotionality_error_intervals","rE_emotionality_error_intervals")))
df_tidy[ , values:=as.numeric(values)]
df_tidy[ , c("lci", "uci") := tstrsplit(gsub("[()]","",intervals),split=",",type.convert = TRUE)]
df_tidy[ , condition := c("rG_activity", "rG_persistence", "rE_activity", "rE_persistence", "rG_emotionality", "rE_emotionality")[variable]]
df_tidy[ , c("what","type") := tstrsplit(condition,split="_")]

ggplot(df_tidy) + 
  aes(x=age, y=values, ymin=lci, ymax=uci,fill=what) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black", width = 0.7) + 
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.7),width=0.25) + 
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=1) + 
  scale_fill_grey(
    start = 0.8,
    end = 0.475,
    na.value = "red",
    aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  geom_text(size=2.75,aes(label=values,y=if_else(values > 0, uci, lci) + .1 * if_else(values > 0, 1, -1)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(y = "Correlation") +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), legend.margin=margin(-15, 0, 0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("6", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "slope", "intercept"),
                   labels = c("6"="Age 6", "12"="Age 12", "18"="Age 18", "24"="Age 24", "30"="Age 30", "36"="Age 36", "slope", "intercept"))
```

Due to missing data, there are no bars present for activity at age 36. I would like to replace this empty space with an N/A label to get something like below. Could I get some tips or advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can just add `geom_text` for the empty rows in `df_tidy` dynamically.

BLUF, add this to your code

```r
+ geom_text(data = ~ unique(.[is.na(values),], by = c("age", "type")), label  ="N/A", y = 0)
```

In all,

```r
ggplot(df_tidy) + 
  aes(x=age, y=values, ymin=lci, ymax=uci,fill=what) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black", width = 0.7) + 
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.7),width=0.25) + 
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=1) + 
  scale_fill_grey(
    start = 0.8,
    end = 0.475,
    na.value = "red",
    aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  geom_text(size=2.75,aes(label=values,y=if_else(values > 0, uci, lci) + .1 * if_else(values > 0, 1, -1)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(y = "Correlation") +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), legend.margin=margin(-15, 0, 0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("6", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "slope", "intercept"),
                   labels = c("6"="Age 6", "12"="Age 12", "18"="Age 18", "24"="Age 24", "30"="Age 30", "36"="Age 36", "slope", "intercept")) + 
  geom_text(data = ~ unique(.[is.na(values),],
            by = c("age", "type")), label = "N/A", y = 0)
```

[image: ggplot with "N/A" label]

I'm using the rlang-style `~`-function for `data=`, subsetting the data as it was passed to `ggplot(.)`. While in this example we could easily use `df_tidy` directly, there are many users who `%>%`-pipe data into ggplot, and the risk of using the *raw* dataframe there is that columns are changed or not available. The use of `.` in the `data=~`-expression is that it is updated to what ggplot knows.

Comment: It's telling me 'object '.' not found, how did you run this on your end? My apologies, I think I'm missing something. Edit: I see, got it now.

Comment: Interesting, you appear to have `dplyr` loaded but not be able to use the imported `rlang`-style `~`-expressions. Okay, easy enough, replace `data = ~ unique(.[...` with `data = function(z) unique(z[...`. (Assuming it's a `data.table`, of course.)

Comment: Scratch that ... incomplete copy/paste/edit error, rookie mistake on my part. It's fixed, add the `~` to your code (edited above).

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, thanks! Minor question (can make a new post if need be), but I would like to reverse the order of my rG and rE columns on my figure, such that rG comes first, then rE. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Yes. Just about every question that asks about reordering axis/labels/colors etc are resolved by converting the variable to a `factor` where _you_ explicitly control the order. In this case, run `df_tidy[, what := factor(what, levels = c("rG", "rE"))]` and replot.

Comment: Thanks. If you look at the bottom right of the figure you produced (the intercept for "persistence"), do you know of a way to manually edit the location of that label (the "-0.006") so that it is appropriately located above the error bar, like the other labels? Same goes of the "-0.024" intercept label of "activity" and "emotionality". I am not sure why those are selectively messed up/out of place, whereas the labels on the rest the figure have correct positions (right above the error bar).

Comment: On the row with `0.006`, your `uci` and `lci` appear swapped, that would be a good thing to address there. It might suffice to reduce your `y=` component of the text to `y=if_else(values > 0, pmax(uci, lci) + 0.1, pmin(uci, lci) - 0.1)`, though you may want to look at why your `uci` is below your `lci`, seems counter-intuitive without knowledge of your process or other context.